# Como adicionar a um campo HTTParty o valor de outro campo

Tags: ruby, http-request, cucumber

Por exemplo no campo "password_confirm" eu quero adicionar o campo "password".

```
@@base_url  = 'https://api-de-tarefas.herokuapp.com/users'
    @@body = 
    {
    "user": {
    "email": Faker::Internet.email,
    "password":  Faker::Number(6),
    "password_confirmation": 

     }    
}.to_json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas acho que basta jogar o password numa variável:

```
password = Faker::Number(6)

@@base_url  = 'https://api-de-tarefas.herokuapp.com/users'


    @@body = 
    {
    "user": {
    "email": Faker::Internet.email,
    "password":  password,
    "password_confirmation": password

     }    
}.to_json
```